# iterate over certain elements of a list, not a data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I am trying to modify certain items from a list based on a criteria (starts with "rr_esp") in the render.data list.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

per <- 2015:2019
render.data <- list(
  emision = structure(
    list(
      AÑO = c(2017, 2018, 2019), 
      TRABAJADORESMES_r = c(58147, 57937, 24818), 
      MASA_r = c(3439195127, 4091347036.2, 2441068565.77), 
      TRABAJADORESMESsinDOM = c(58147L, 57928L, 24818L), 
      MESES = c(12, 12, 5)
    ), 
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
    row.names = c(NA, -3L)
  ),
  siniestros = structure(
    list(
      AÑO = c(2017, 2018, 2019), 
      N = c(388L, 327L, 115L), 
      GR_66 = c(64, 53, 15), 
      JU = c(41L, 5L, 0L), 
      JN = c(20, 19, 6), 
      PORINC_66s = c(437.22, 293.73, 82.12), 
      EDADs = c(15142L, 12886L, 4712L), 
      SALARIOs = c(13707950.67, 15151144.7, 4800075.4)
    ), 
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
    row.names = c(NA, -3L)
  ),
  rr_esp1 = structure(
    list(
      AÑO = c(2017, 2018, 2019), 
      MESES = c(12, 12, 5),
      TRAB_PROM = c(4845.58, 4828.08, 4963.60), 
      PORINC = c(6.83, 5.54, 5.47), 
      SALARIO = c(35329.76, 46333.77, 41739.78), 
      EDAD = c(39.02, 39.40, 40.97)
    ), 
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
    row.names = c(NA, -3L)
  ),
  rr_esp7 = structure(
    list(
      AÑO = c(2017, 2018, 2019), 
      JUI_LIQ = c(1539624.21, 318726, 0), 
      JUI_RVA = c(24434809.51, 2292925.89, 0), 
      JUI_IBNR = c(0, 25284030.0174036, 22434092.26), 
      JUI_ULT = c(25974433.72, 27895681.90, 22434092.26), 
      CM_JUICIO = c(1505898.34, 1806002.14, 1557923.07)
    ), 
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
    row.names = c(NA, -3L)
  )
)
```

When apply a loop over their elements, they loses their original itemnames
Afterwards, I dont know a better way to iterate a subset of list elements and assign them a new value. I google it but I do not find a critical solution for list instead of data.frames.

```
 render.data <- invisible(lapply(seq_along(render.data), function(i){
    if(startsWith(names(render.data)[i], prefix = "rr_esp")){
      render.data[[i]] %>% 
       complete(`AÑO` = per) %>% 
       gather(
         key = "metrica", value = "valor", -`AÑO`
       ) %>% 
       mutate(# orden de las metricas
         metrica = factor(metrica, levels = unique(metrica))
       ) %>% 
       spread(
         key = `AÑO`, value = "valor"
       )} else{
         render.data[[i]]
       }
      setNames(render.data[[i]], names(render.data)[i])
  }))
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data. Also include relevant library calls - looks like `tidyr` and `dplyr`, but it's good to be sure.

Comment: echo. I have added it

Comment: I think the main problem is that your function doesn't `return` anything. If you had `function(x) { x + 1; names(x) = "hello" }`, the `x + 1` is calculated, but the function just returns `"hello"`. Probably you'd want `function(x) { x <- x + 1; names(x) <- "hello"; return(x)}` to modify the `x` value, modify the `x` name, and return the modified value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a case where a `for` loop is much clearer than an `lapply`. The main advantages of `lapply` are (a) that it pre-allocates a data structure for the result and (b) has simple syntax to apply a simple function. You already have a data structure for the result, and your function is complex. I don't know what your expected output is, but I would try this:

```
# find elements to modify
rr_elements = which(startsWith(names(render.data), prefix = "rr_esp"))

# modify in for loop
for (i in rr_elements) {
  render.data[[i]] = render.data[[i]] %>%
    complete(`AÑO` = per) %>%
    gather(key = "metrica", value = "valor",-`AÑO`) %>%
    mutate(# orden de las metricas
      metrica = factor(metrica, levels = unique(metrica))) %>%
    spread(key = `AÑO`, value = "valor")
}
```

If you want to make this code more re-usable, create a function for the operation on one data frame, and then you can use it easily with `for` or `lapply`. In general, I'd say that picking the data frames on which to use the function is better done *externally* than *internally*. (That is, I don't like how you have an `if()` statement checking the name *inside* the function. Do this logic *outside* the function, and only give the function the data you want it to use.)

```
foo = function(data) {
  data %>%
    complete(`AÑO` = per) %>%
    gather(key = "metrica", value = "valor",-`AÑO`) %>%
    mutate(# orden de las metricas
      metrica = factor(metrica, levels = unique(metrica))) %>%
    spread(key = `AÑO`, value = "valor")
}

# now the for loop or lapply is simple:
rr_elements = which(startsWith(names(render.data), prefix = "rr_esp"))

# for loop version
for (i in rr_elements) {
  render.data[[i]] = foo(render.data[[i]])
}

# lapply version
render.data[rr_elements] = lapply(render.data[rr_elements], foo)
```

Comment: thanks!! It was a wonderful clarification to pick data.frames externally to avoid conticional if.
I have similar doubts when you mutate a column data.frame based in other yes/no column. I am using `if_else` statement